# How do I display multiple tables in ASP.NET MVC view from a multi-table output stored procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I am trying to display two tables in my ASP.NET MVC view from a stored procedure which returns 2 tables. When I tried to access the stored procedure result, I was able to retrieve only the first result set and not the second one.

In the stored procedure result, both the tables are obtained by querying multiple tables in the database. Stored procedure is saved as testsp

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [testsp] 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 20 CONCAT(col1,' : ', col2) AS 'cols'
    FROM table1 
    WHERE CreatedBy IN (SELECT col11 FROM table2 
                        WHERE col12 = 456 AND Curr = 1)
    ORDER BY CreatedAt DESC

    SELECT TOP 20 CONCAT(col1,' : ', col2) AS 'cols'
    FROM table1 
    WHERE CreatedBy = (SELECT col1 FROM table2 WHERE col12 = 123)
    ORDER BY CreatedAt DESC
END
```

After creating the stored procedure, I included the stored procedure in the model and tried to access it in the controller using the following code:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DBEntities r = new DBEntities();
        var data = r.testsp().ToList();
        ViewBag.tests = data;
        return View();
    }
}
```

In the view, I tried to display it using the following code:

```
<table id="data" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.tests)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This displayed the first table and not the second one.

How do I access both tables from the stored procedure result, in the controller and display them in the view?

Comment: You really have two questions: 1. How do I capture multiple result sets from a SP. 2. How do I display both on the same page.  Please read this to solve part 1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776426/asp-net-mvc-and-linq-general-questions

Comment: Please tag the database used. i.e. SQL Server or Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

SP cannot have simply two selects. SP would exit after the first select command execution. 
Three Choices:

1. Use Union to combine both the selects.
2. Define REFCUR and return the cursor from SP
3. For a more advanced solution develop UDT(User Defined Types).

Comment: Assuming this is for **SQL Server**: a stored procedure can easily have **any number** of `SELECT` - it would ***NOT*** "exit" after the first select - that's just plain wrong!